# Is there a way to force onFinish from CountDownTimer?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

Is there a method or an attribute that allows the CountDownTimer to become 0 and force the onFinish() method?

Imagine this: a pass and play game has a timer and a "Pass" button. Once the player does what he/she needs to do, he/she can touch the "Pass" button and pass it to the next player. If he/she gets stuck and the timer runs out, he/she is to pass the game along, essentially missing their turn.

Basically, I need to implement the latter. Thanks.

EDIT: I have a TextView that is created during onFinish(), textview is linked to a proper ID and set it's text to say "Hello World." When the timer runs out, the text is displayed. When I have the method containing CountDownTimer.cancel(), the text is not displayed but the timer does stop ticking down.

Comment: You want to stop the countdown timer when a player press the Pass button?

Comment: Yes, because you are essentially ending your turn. This either restarts the timer, or terminates it and starts a new one. I will be trying the cancel() method as Alex mentioned.

Comment: Solved. Thank you, Alex. I would upvote but I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call `CountDownTimer.cancel()` and, immediately after that, call what you're doing in `onFinish()`

Comment: Will try this as soon as I can. I was not aware that the cancel() method triggers onFinish()

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work. I have a TextView that is created during the onFinish(), linked to a proper ID and set it's text to say "Hello World." When the timer runs out, the text is displayed. When I have the method containing CountDownTimer.cancel(), the text is not displayed but the timer does stop ticking down.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot. When you said call whatever in onFinish() I thought that it was implicit that onFinish() would be called if cancel() was called. I had to explicitly call CountDownTimer.onFinish() after I call CountDownTimer.cancel().